# How to get the cause of an insert() error using ContentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a code that inserts a row into a DB, using a custom ContentProvider:

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI, UserTable.TABLE_NAME);
Uri resultUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, contentValues);
boolean success = (Long.parseLong(resultUri.getLastPathSegment()) != -1);
```

The insert() method is defined in the ContentProvider as follows:

```
public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider {

// ...

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        String table = getTableName(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long value = database.insert(table, null, initialValues);
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(value));
    }

}
```

I've noticed that, sometimes, the insertion fails by returning a row ID equals to -1 (as you can see in the third line of the first code, `success` should become false). The problem is that I can't understand the reason because LogCat doesn't print any exception related to SqlLite.
Why the ContentProvider does not inform me about the cause of those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an exception, use [insertOrThrow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) instead.

Comment: WOW! I didn't notice about this, I'll try